# update and install ionic and ios

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

Try updating to enhance ionic some problems with updating my application in iTunes Connect. Now after updating I get this error when trying to install again and I can not.

```
MacBook-Pro:app_view_android lixsys$ ionic build ionic
******************************************************
Dependency warning - for the CLI to run correctly,      
it is highly suggested to install/upgrade the following:     

Install ios-deploy to deploy iOS applications to devices. `npm install -g ios-deploy` (may require sudo)
```

---

```
Unknown platforms: ionic
MacBook-Pro:app_view_android lixsys$ npm install -g ios-deploy
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /Users/lixsys/.npm/ios-deploy/1.8.3/package.tgz
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ios-deploy"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [  '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:46:53',
npm ERR!      'FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:99:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/lixsys/app_view_android/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a clue:

> npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator

Seems that you need to run the npm install as superuser:

> $ **sudo** npm install -g ios-deploy

This is probably caused because npm was installed with restrictive permissions. To prevent that kind of issues on Mac it would be interesting for you to install npm through [Node Version Manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nvm) so you won't require sudo permissions for that kind of things.